# ol-debug.js - Assertion failed: 3rd instruction should be a number

Tags: javascript, debugging, openlayers-3, assertions

I'm upgrading an online application from OpenLayers 3.0 to the current version 3.9.

Changing to the new vector api ( https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0 ) I receive the following error (using ol-debug.js ):

> Assertion failed: 3rd instruction should be a number
>
> goog.debug.Error@  ...  /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:2606:17
>   goog.asserts.AssertionError@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:4307:1
>   goog.asserts.doAssertFailure_@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:4366:11 goog.asserts.assert@ 
>   ...  /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:4396:1
>   ol.render.canvas.Replay.prototype.replay_@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:60032:1
>   ol.render.canvas.Replay.prototype.replay@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:60094:1
>   ol.render.canvas.ReplayGroup.prototype.replay@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:61576:1
>   ol.renderer.canvas.VectorLayer.prototype.composeFrame@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:74555:1
>   ol.renderer.canvas.Map.prototype.renderFrame@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:74969:7
>   ol.Map.prototype.renderFrame_@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:84629:3
>   goog.async.AnimationDelay.prototype.doAction_@  ... 
>   /InViTo_3/js/ol-debug.js?ver=20140502:39611:3

In practice I have two vector layers build from geojsons:

```
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures( jsondata, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:' + jsondata.srid} )
})
```

The first layer (polylines) is working perfectly.
The loading of the second (polygons) is causing the error and makes all the map instable (not refreshing correctly).

A similar error is reported at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/hA5wNYL3CxE
I tried to explicit the projection, but It didn't helped.

Here the error demo:
http://130.192.92.243:8000/~invitest/?page_id=2&pname=project&act=view&cid=259

Thank you,
Rickyx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strings, such as `"1"` as line width in your styles for some features. The assertion error indicates that the width must be a number: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.style.Stroke.html

Comment: Yesss!
How I should have realized this mistake using the assertions?
Thank you, Rickyx!

Comment: @Rickyx Like most JS applications, ol3 does not always check the type of inputs. Invalid inputs are generally accepted until they are actually used for some operation. Invalid input might cause all sorts of issues. In this case, an assertion was triggered in the renderer. If you get an exception, find it's source and follow the call chain upwards.